# Phonegap Http post not working

Tags: angularjs, http, phonegap

I'm having problem posting my request to node server through phonegap, while if i post the same request through rest tools like postman it successfully fires:
While seeing  the network tab i realize that the request looks like 
    http://localhost:3000/proxy/myApi
and probably this is the reason I'm not able to fire my request, i tried finding '/proxy' in my http interceptor post requests, but it the url seems fine there.

Could someone please help me with this, Get requests are working all fine, it's only the problem with post.

Comment: Will you show your node server url and url you are passing in post call??